# Subtracting at the beginning of a string

Tags: c++

I have a string that I need to keep subtracting from the beginning while the letters continuously move as well. For example:

> ABC DEF GHI JK needs to look like this 
>   BCD EFG HIJ K and then
>   CDE FGH IJK

I have some code, but the letters are not moving individually:

```
int main()
{
    string code, default_Code;
    default_Code = "TCAATGTAACGCGCTACCCGGAGCTCTGGGCCCAAATTTCATCCACT";         
    start_C = "AUG";
    code.reserve(100);
    int i = 0, a = 0, c =0;
    char choice;

    for (int j = 3; j < code.length(); j += 4)   // Creating space between 3 letters
    {
        code.insert(j, 1, ' ');
    }

    do {
        i = 0;
        do {                                                // Looping to create an open reading frame.
            for (int b = 0; b*3 < code.length(); b++) {         //  moving through the code 
                for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                    cout << code[(a + b*3) + i];
                }
            }
            i++;
            cout << endl;
        } while (i < 3);

        reverse(code.rbegin(), code.rend());            // Reversing to create the second set reading frame.

        c++;
        cout << endl; 

    } while (c < 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Attempted to clean up the formatting a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to put space characters into the string, instead of just inserting them in the output, you could do something like this:

```
std::string code("TCAATGTAACGCGCTACCCGGAGCTCTGGGCCCAAATTTCATCCACT");

// a repeating pattern of offsets
int x[4] = { 1, 1, 2, 0 };

for (size_t i = 3; i < code.length(); i +=4)
{
    code.insert(i, 1, ' ');
}

while (code.length() > 0)
{
    printf("%s\n", code.c_str());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < code.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        // new char is either 1, 2, or 0 bytes ahead
        size_t j = i + x[i % 4];

        // in case it's 2 bytes at the end, just get the last
        code[i] = code[j < code.length() ? j : j - 1];
    }

    // and throw away the leftover at the end
    code.resize(code.length() - 1);
}
```

EDIT> To respond to the comments below:

If you try inserting this code before the printf statement...

```
    size_t t = code.find("ATC");
    if (t != std::string::npos)
    {
        code.replace(t, 3, " M ");
    }
```

...you'll see that code.find("ATC") does *not* find "A TC" or "AT C". It doesn't find it until the third line of output when "ATC" appears in the string without any spaces in between the letters. I have spaces inserted the actual string data just as your original code did.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that I keep running into the same problem every time. Now I am supposed to look for a certain block of letters. Let's take from my example up top. Let's say I want to look for DEF. When the next block goes to BCD EFG HIJ, etc. there should not be a DEF anymore. However, it seems to not be the case when I run my program.

Comment: It seems to find all instances of DEF even when there is a space between the letters. I will post the code I use below to search and replace what I am looking for.

Comment: size_t pos = code.find("ATG");
if (pos != string::npos){code.replace(code.find("ATG"), 3, " M ");}

Comment: The code, as I've written it above, will *not* find all instances of, for example, "ATG", using code.find("ATG") when the letters are separated by spaces. See my edit in my answer above.

Comment: So I have copied and pasted the exact same code and it does not find ATC in the first line(which is good), finds ATC in the second line(which is good), but also finds it in the 3rd line(Not so good).

Comment: Is it something that I have wrong? I have put the new code right above the printf, inside the while loop.

Comment: And now it works, i made it a function and did the search within that function and viola! thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the first character from the string, simply iterate over your start positions in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Extracting certain part out from a string object.

Leave the string to be printed in one variable, and the formated output string in another.

Metacode:

std::string value = "ABCDEFG"
std::string output;

value = value.substr(2, value.size()-3);

// create output
output = value.. etc..

Answer (score 0):

You're code doesn't print anything out because you're working on `code` but you never actually set that variable to anything except an empty string. I assume this is just because the code you posted is modified from what you're actually using.

I'd suggest a different way of doing this.

Write a function that takes an input string and returns a the data with the spaces inserted. Then call the function repeatedly with the initial characters removed.

Here's a program that prints out your string divided into groups of three letters, removing the first letter after each printed line until nothing is printed.

```
void print_with_spaces(string::const_iterator begin,string::const_iterator end) {
    int i=0;
    while(begin!=end) {
        cout << *begin++;
        if(++i % 3 == 0)
            cout << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    string code = "TCAATGTAACGCGCTACCCGGAGCTCTGGGCCCAAATTTCATCCACT";

    string::const_iterator i = code.begin();
    while(i!=code.end())
        print_with_spaces(i++,code.end());
}
```

Comment: so what if I just wanted to loop it 3 times? I wouldn't be able to put numerical values there...

Comment: Instead of `while(i!=code.end())` you would have `for(int j=0;j<3;++j)`

Comment: Thank you, but I have one more question... When I try to read a group of letters inside that code, it will keep reading it, even if it has separated. For example,                                             TCA ATG TAA CGC GCT ACC CGG AGC TCT GGG CCC AAA TTT CAT CCA CT
CAA TGT AAC GCG CTA CCC GGA GCT CTG GGC CCA AAT TTC ATC CAC T             For the second block on the first line, there is ATG, and then there is not an ATG on the second line, but the compiler is still reading it. Is there some way to change the function where bout << ' '; to actually inserting a space like using insert fn.

Comment: Let me know if I need to clarify myself. It seems to me that using cout << ' ' doesn't read it as actually a space.

Comment: `cout << ' '` is _writing_ a space to the console. I'm not sure what you mean by 'the compiler is still reading it'. Yes, there is a way to change the `print_with_spaces` function so that instead of printing the string with spaces it creates a new string with spaces inserted. You would change the function in the following ways: 1) it would have a local string variable. 2) instead of printing out the characters it would insert those characters into its string variable. 3) it would return the string variable.